# Inconsistent #Value! error using Left/Find function for Date/Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, valueerror

I am trying to pull the DATE out of a combined Date/Time set of data, and the LEFT/FIND formula works [=LEFT([@[Date/Time]],FIND(" ",$Q259))] for the whole worksheet except for a specific chunk of data, and I can't figure out what makes it different. The only clue I'm noticing is that it's saying 'tt' instead of AM/PM, but that hasn't lead me to a solution.

I've tried adjusting the formatting of the date/time, as well as trying other formula options to dodge the whole problem.

Comment: sometimes doing "=left(some_function)*1" will get the result recognized as a number.

Comment: Date/Time are usually stored in Excel as Decimals and formatted to look like a text string, they are not actual strings so there is no space.  to get just the date you would do: `=INT([@[Date/Time]])` and format it as a date.

Comment: Agree with @ScottCraner Sir, `INT()` is the perfect way to deal with it, however for fun one can use `TEXTSPLIT()` by splitting using decimals.